# How would I organize a Postgres db for a list of restaurants and their menu items?

Tags: postgresql

I'm playing around with Postgres and trying to get the hang of more complex issues. Imagine I have a large set of restaurants in each of the 50 U.S. states. Each restaurant contains a menu, and each menu contains a set of items which contain things like price, description, etc. What would be a good way to organize the data?

My initial thought, which I'm sure is way wrong, would be to have a db per state. Within that would be a list of restaurants (and any basic details like address, phone number, rating, etc). Then, I'd have one db per restaurant which represents the menu. This db would contain columns that define each menu entry.

Is this totally off the mark? Is there a more ideal way to accomplish this? My current experience playing around with Postgres has just been limited to a single database.

I'm just looking for a good description, not a bunch of code. This is more a general architectural question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always recommend you first write down all the individual things you want to store in the database, at the most *atomic form* that makes sense for your application.

In this example, I am assuming that its a franchise restaurant, and you want to track its various stores and their offerings.

A sample schema:

1. A table for ingredients, possible columns could be:

   - Name
   - Supplier
2. A table for menu items, possible columns could be:

   - Name
   - Descirption
   - Is Vegan
   - Has Nuts
   - Is Kosher
3. A table that links a menu item with its ingredients:

   - MenuItemPK
   - IngredientItemPK
4. A table for each restaurant:

   - Name
   - Owner
   - Contact Information
5. A table for each restaurant location:

   - RestaurantPK
   - Branch Name
   - City
   - State
   - ZIP
   - Opening Hours
6. A table that links a restaurant with its menus:

   - RestaurantLocationPK
   - Menu Name (for example, 'weekend dinner')
   - Menu Descirption
7. A table that links a menu with its items:

   - MenuItemPK
   - MenuPK

Comment: `s/for each/containing every/g`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really about **relational database design**, not Postgresql per se, so that's something for you to track down and learn about.

Your description of your first idea is heading down the right path, except instead of separate databases, these different entities should be stored in separate *tables*. (You'd break things out into separate databases only when there's no real likelihood you'd ever need to compare the items with each other, or search across all of them, etc. And in your description, these things would all best be in one database.)